# Excel Conditional Formatting - Comparing One Column to Every Other Column

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm stuck on a problem where I want to compare one column to every other column and highlight matches. [In my example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoU2h.png) I have three columns with three rows each. I want to compare the column A to column B then column A to column C, and fill in if they match. They're comparing based off their respective rows. So if column A is comparing using row 1, it will be comparing to B and C's row 1. I know a formula like `=$A1=$B1` would compare column A and B with each other. But is there anyway to modify that so I will work with C and any other columns I add in the future? Ideally would it be possible to keep it as one rule?

Answer (score 0):

If your data in is `A1:C3`, the formula you need for your conditional formatting condition of cell `A1` is

`=COUNTIF($A1:$C1,A1)>1`

Use the format painter to copy the format of cell `A1` to range `A1:C3`.

If you wanted to do this by columns instead of by rows, the formula to use would be

`=COUNTIF(A$1:A$3,A1)>1`